# Php system() hangs?

Tags: php, python, system

I have program where:

- run infinite loop in php where i get new records to process, save in file
- run python script where in pool script process this records

php code:

```
while(true) {
    $records = get_records();
    file_put_contents($file_name, json_encode($records));
    echo "php:system:before";
    system("python script.py $file_name");
    echo "php:system:before";
}
```

python code:

```
import json
import os
import sys
import time
import random
import urllib2
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from os.path import isdir
from platform import system
from lib import Logger

def do_something(record):
    # ... some operations
    print("python:record:done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    records = read_records
    pool = Pool(4)
    pool.map(do_something, records)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print("python:done")
```

But from time to time process hangs.

My logs:

```
php:system:start
python:record:done
python:record:done
python:record:done
python:record:done
python:record:done
python:record:done
python:record:done
python:done
<- here I expect php:system:before
```

but twice a day I don't get it and I reset program.
Where is error, and why script hangs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Apache:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44942

Comment: Are you sure this is running behind apache? Looks more like a shell script / cronjob.

Comment: Ah okay. How come you are using php for this bit, and python for the rest? Why not just use python

Comment: Hi. It wasn't my decision. System requirements were system written in php, but next I need multiprocessing module from Python and it's system hack.
Are other options to run external program from php?

Comment: Do you need the response from the call?

Comment: I don't need response from call.

Comment: Maybe try exec() or passthru()